# Как сделать автоматичекую загрузку модулей Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuex

В проекте использую **Vue** + **Vuex**. Накопилось много `vuex-модулей`. Сейчас они все подключабются так:

```js
import { module_1 } from 'Store/modules/module_1';
import { module_2 } from 'Store/modules/module_2';
...
import { module_n } from 'Store/modules/module_n';
```

Именование модулей и директорий в [`snake_case`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Как можно это упростить или сделать эту загрузку автоматической?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведу один из вариантов решения.

Структура директорий:

```
- store
- - modules
- - - module_1
- - - ...
- - - module_n
- - - - index.ts
- - - - actions.ts
- - - - getters.ts
- - - - mutations.ts
- - autoloader.ts
- - index.ts
- - types.ts
```

Типы(`types.ts`):

```
export type User {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
}

export interface UserState {
  users: User[]
}

export interface RootState {}
```

Пример модуля:

```
import { getters } from './getters'
import { actions } from './actions'
import { mutations } from './mutations'
import type { Module } from 'vuex'
import type { UserState, RootState } from '@/store/types'

const state: UserState = {
  users: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'jd@ya.ru'
  }],
}

const user: Module<UserState, RootState> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
}

export default user
```

Загрузчик:

```
import type { Module } from 'vuex'
import type { RootState } from './types'

export type ModuleProperty = { 
  [key: string]: Module<object, RootState>
}

/**
 * @returns {ModuleProperty}
 */
export default function autoloader() {
  const modules: ModuleProperty = {}

  const context = require.context('./modules', true, /index\.ts$/i)

  context.keys().forEach((path) => {
    const find = /(?<module_name>\w+)\/index\.ts/.exec(path)

    const module_name = find?.groups?.module_name

    if (module_name) {
      const module = context(path)

      modules[module_name] = module.default
    }
  })

  return modules
}
```

index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import autoloader from './autoloader'

import type { RootState } from './types'
import type { ModuleTree, StoreOptions } from 'vuex'

const modules: ModuleTree<RootState> = autoloader()

const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  modules,
}

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store<RootState>(store)
```

***Дополнительная информация***:

- [?.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [require.context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context)